# How to search for, or get entryId with Kaltura API

Tags: api, kaltura

Hi I'm trying to get the entryId back (so I can update thumbnails) with the kaltura API. How do i do this. My thought is to use title and category. But can't figure out how to do that. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `list` action on the `media` service - [see here for ducomentation](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/service/media/action/list).

You can use the `nameEqual` field to search for the specific entry. I suggest search by the name. If you want, you have more field you can search on in the filter